# Exception while configuring signer certifiate in WebSphere

Tags: java, websphere

I have to call a webservice to purge files (delete from its child servers also) from remote server. In that course I am using a URL which has https in it.

WebSphere throws a `java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error`.

Later I found and configured signer certificate, By retrieving the certificate information using host name and port number. I saved this new singer certificate and after that i didnt get that exception.

But the problem is in some WebSphere am able to do this and in some am not able to do. In other I am getting this error: `DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.`

So here is my question why am not able to configure in other WebSphere, what could be the reason? am I doing it in wrong way?

Comment: Is there some exception ID logged? I think this APAR is relevant to your case - http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ92567

Comment: But how can we fix that? i gone through the link there is no solution for it?

Comment: May you check your Java version using 'java -version', making sure you are using JRE shipped with WebSphere? APAR mentioned by TSF tells that fix was planned for Java 1.4.2 SR14,  Java 5.0 SR13, and Java 6.0 SR10. Let's see if you're using a version newer than these.

Comment: Can you try disabling the "Dynamically update the run time when SSL configuration changes occur" option on the WAS that throws the "DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big" error? Then restart the WAS and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=127, too big.

This is because the certificate you are trying to import is not a DER format file. I got this error with a PKCS7 file.